# Is there a way to shorten this jquery code?

Tags: jquery, addclass

I got a jquery script but its to long (I think)
Is there a way to make this code shorter? 
The code adds classes to a button and a paragraph so they show up with their own text every button got his own text (paragraph).

---

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xxjxve6b/)

I'm talking about the jquery code ;) But i can change the html and the css aswell if needed

```
$(function() {                       //run when the DOM is ready
  $(".button-case.een").click(function() {  //use a class, since your ID gets mangled
    $(".button-case.een").toggleClass("active"); 
    $("p.inner-p.een").toggleClass("active"); //add the class to the clicked element
  });
  $(".button-case.twee").click(function() {  //use a class, since your ID gets mangled
    $(".button-case.twee").toggleClass("active"); 
    $("p.inner-p.twee").toggleClass("active"); //add the class to the clicked element
  });
  $(".button-case.drie").click(function() {  //use a class, since your ID gets mangled
    $(".button-case.drie").toggleClass("active"); 
    $("p.inner-p.drie").toggleClass("active"); //add the class to the clicked element
  });
  $(".button-case.vier").click(function() {  //use a class, since your ID gets mangled
    $(".button-case.vier").toggleClass("active"); 
    $("p.inner-p.vier").toggleClass("active"); //add the class to the clicked element
  });
  $(".button-case.vijf").click(function() {  //use a class, since your ID gets mangled
    $(".button-case.vijf").toggleClass("active"); 
    $("p.inner-p.vijf").toggleClass("active"); //add the class to the clicked element
  });
  $(".button-case.zes").click(function() {  //use a class, since your ID gets mangled
    $(".button-case.zes").toggleClass("active"); 
    $("p.inner-p.zes").toggleClass("active"); //add the class to the clicked element
  });
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `this` within the event handler to refer to the element which raised the event. From there you can traverse to DOM to amend the required elements. Try this:

```
$(".button-case").click(function () { 
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $(this).next('p').toggleClass("active");
});
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xxjxve6b/1/)

You could event make it one line by using `add` if you really wanted to:

```
$(".button-case").click(function () { 
    $(this).add($(this).next()).toggleClass("active");
});
```

However this could be a little unsightly.

Comment: Don't you forget a *p* selector?

Comment: @Fractaliste in this case it's not required. However I usually include them to stop future DOM changes from breaking the JS code.

Answer (score 2):

You could

```js
$(function() { //run when the DOM is ready
  $(".button-case").click(function() { //use a class, since your ID gets mangled
    //here this refers to the clicked button so 
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $(this).next().toggleClass("active"); //add the class to the clicked element
  });
});
```

```css
#buttons-case {
  max-width: 707px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.button-case {
  border: 1px solid #8A8A8A;
  color: #8A8A8A;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 12px;
  font: 300 15px/0.925"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.btn {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 169px;
  margin: 9px 21px auto;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 12px;
}
.btn.active {
  height: 60px;
  width: 707px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 500;
  background: #fff;
  padding-left: 24px;
  padding-top: 16px;
}
.button-case.active {
  text-align: left;
}
.button-holder {
  max-width: 707px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
p.inner-p {
  display: none;
}
p.inner-p.active {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 600;
  top: 35px;
  left: 46px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button-holder">
  <div id="buttons-case">
    <a href="#" class="button-case btn een">GepasteTypografie</a>
    <p class="inner-p een">eerste</p>
    <a href="#" class="button-case btn twee">Grafische elementen</a>
    <p class="inner-p twee">tweede</p>
    <a href="#" class="button-case btn drie">Ga naar</a>
    <p class="inner-p drie">derde</p>
    <a href="#" class="button-case btn vier">Duidelijk werkproces</a>
    <p class="inner-p vier">vierde</p>
    <a href="#" class="button-case btn vijf">Responsive design</a>
    <p class="inner-p vijf">vijfde</p>
    <a href="#" class="button-case btn zes">Gebruiksvriendelijk</a>
    <p class="inner-p zes">zesde</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Both answers worked thx i'll go with the other one. Because its a little shorter Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Create a function for toggle and send information of class to that function:

```
function toggleFunc(data) {
    $(".button-case." + data).click(function() {
    $(".button-case." + data).toggleClass("active"); 
    $("p.inner-p." + data).toggleClass("active");
});

$(function() {
    toggleFunc('een');
    toggleFunc('twee');
    toggleFunc('drie');
    toggleFunc('vier');
    toggleFunc('vijf');
    toggleFunc('zes');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add all selectors to array and loop through it to bind everything you need. Something like this:

```
$(function() {
    var sels = [$(".button-case.een"), $(".button-case.twee"), /* ... */];

    for (var i = 0, max = sels.length; i < max; i++ {
        var sel = sels[i];
        sel.on('click', function() {/* code */});
    }

});
```

Note, that this is just example. If it is better you can actually write array with classes or even object with all your metadata about each binding and loop through it.

You can also combine this approach with optimizations from the other answers, as well.